# How to calculate the digits of a huge number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Example, $2^{2014}$ has $607$ digits. How many digits are in $5^{2014}$?

Is there any relation between the two numbers? I found the answer to be $1009$ because there exists a pattern in the repeating digits.

Comment: $5^{2014}$ has $1408$ digits.

Comment: Could you post ur answer and works?

Comment: You first.${}{}$

Answer (score 4):

$2^n \cdot 5^n = 10^n$, which has $n+1$ digits.  When we multiply there will be a carry.  So if $2^n$ has $m$ digits, $5^n$ has $n-m+1$ digits.[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%5E2014) shows it has $1408$ digits

Comment: Now that's clever. I like it (+1)!

Comment: Why is this? It sure works, why?

Comment: It's not quite right, as you can see by trying $n=1$ or $2$. In fact $5^n$ has $n-m+1$ digits. (You seem to have assumed that $m$ digits multiplied by $k$ digits has $m+k$ or $m+k+1$ digits, whereas in fact it has $m+k-1$ or $m+k$ digits.)

Comment: @TonyK:  You are correct, thanks.

Comment: @user139024:  Fleshing out what TonyK says, if $a$ has $m$ digits and $b$ has $k$ digits, we have $10^{m-1}\le a \lt 10^m$ and $10^{k-1} \le b \lt 10^k$, so $10^{m+k-2} \le ab \lt 10^{m+k}$.  The fact that we have a carry says $10^{m+k-1}$ is the power of interest.

Comment: Wait If 10^k is the smallest number of k digits, how is b whose number of digit is k smaller than 10^k?

Comment: No, $10^k$ is the smallest number of $k+1$ digits

Answer (score 0):

You can take the base 10 logarithm, and round up. $\log_{10}{5^{2014}} = 2014\log_{10}{5}$. How useful this is depends on whether you can compute the logarithm of 5.

Answer (score 0):

The number of digits in $a^b$ is surely the least integer greater than or equal to $b\log_{10}a$, right?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

if $m$ is the number of digits of a number $x$ then we have:
$$10^{m-1} \leq x < 10^m$$ because $10^k$ is the smallets number having $k$ digits.

We deduce: $$m-1 \leq \log(x)<  m$$ where $\log$ is the decimal logarithm.

Thus:$$m \leq 1+\log(x) < m+1$$ who gives: $$m=[1+\log(x)]$$
where $[y]$ is the integer part of $y$ that is the bigest integer $k$ such that $k \leq y$, that is the unique integer $k$ such that $k \leq y < k+1$)